# constexpr initialization of global variable

Tags: c++, constexpr

If I have a variable declared with storage ie int x; and initialize it with a call to a constexpr function will it have the value determined before any code in main starts executing.

```
constexpr int get_value() { return 5;}

int x = get_value();

int main() {
   return x;
};
```

Comment: Its about constexpr. Is the other question about that.

Comment: @BlairDavidson: How would `constexpr` change anything?

Comment: @BlairDavidson `constexpr` for functions only means "there is at least one set of arguments where compile-time evaluation is possible". In any case, the answers to the linked question clearly indicate that the initialization happens before `main`.

Comment: up to you if you want to remove it.

Comment: @BlairDavidson **A:Yes** / [Constant initialization](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#2) happens because: **1**. `x` is a variable with static storage duration; **2**. the full-expression of its initialization `get_value()` is a [core constant expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5). And it happens [as a consequence of program initiation](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#1) which is before program execution. **BTW**, since this question itself is much more than just "Storage Duration", it has its own value and I don't think this question should be closed either.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20, you have `constinit` for that:

```
constexpr int get_value() { return 5;}

// Still mutable, not constexpr but
// initialized with a value at compile time.
constinit int x = get_value();

int main() {
   return x;
};
```

Comment: I notice that in gcc when I debug i can see the value is set prior to main

Comment: @BlairDavidson I don't think GCC supports `constinit` yet